# Does App Engine handle character encoding differently online vs. locally?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, google-app-engine, unicode, flask

I've written a small web-app which pulls data from a simple mysql DB and displays it via Python and Flask.  The text fields in the database are encoded as utf8_general_ci, and some contain special characters - for example, 'Zürich'.

As Flask/Jinja2 [like to work on unicode](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/api/#unicode), after the query the strings are converted to unicode to be passed into the template.  What's weird is I need a different approach to convert to unicode, depending on whether the code is running locally (Mac laptop) or deployed on GAE.

This works when running locally:

```
return [[unicode(c, encoding='utf-8') if isinstance(c, basestring) else c for c in b] for b in l]
```

This works when deployed on GAE:

```
return [[unicode(c, encoding='latin-1') if isinstance(c, basestring) else c for c in b] for b in l]
```

.

If I run the GAE version locally, 'Zürich' is displayed as 'ZÃ¼rich'.  Vice versa, I get an UnicodeDecode error.

As far as I can tell, the two databases are identical - the online version is a straight dump of the local version.

Answer (score 0):

`Ã¼` is the Mojibake for `ü`.

See "Mojibake" in [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for a discussion of the likely causes.

See [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python) for Python notes on what to do in the source code.  I don't know about Jinja specifics.